# How to add category Path when creating product progrmatically in magento 2

Tags: category, magento2.2, custom, products, programmatically

I want to create products programatically by reading an xml file.
Reading from xml, and creating product part is completed.
I have no idea how to assign the products to category.
This is my xml node for the categories.

```
<categories>Default Category/Wine,Default Category/Collections,Default Category/Spirits,Default Category/Spirits/VODKA/Plain,Default Category for Store 2/Collections,Default Category for Store 2/Wine,Default Category for Store 2/Spirits,Default Category for Store 2/Spirits/VODKA/Plain
    </categories>
```

Extracted categories from the categories xml node below

> Default Category/Wine
>
> Default Category/Collections
>
> Default Category/Spirits,
>
> Default Category/Spirits/VODKA/Plain
>
> Default Category for Store 2/Collections
>
> Default Category for Store 2/Wine
>
> Default Category for Store 2/Spirits
>
> Default Category for Store 2/Spirits/VODKA/Plain

To set the categories i want to use below code set

```
$category_id= array(4,5);
// add your catagory id
$set_product->setCategoryIds($category_id);
```

How can i get the category ids from the xml node `<categories>...</categories>`.

I can get the category id of a last word of category by using below code.

```
$categoryTitle = 'Wine';
$collection = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()
          ->addAttributeToFilter('name',$categoryTitle)->setPageSize(1);
if ($collection->getSize()) {
   $categoryId = $collection->getFirstItem()->getId();
}
```

But i cannot use above code , because i have 2 stores and categories belongs to two stores.Please help me to complete this task.